# Entity Framework: Inheritance with same properties

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem when I try to use Migrations in Entity Framework (Code First).

I have this models:

- PERSON (int Id, string Name)
- FRIEND : PERSON (string Document)
- BESTFRIEND : PERSON (string Document)
- BESTBESTFIEND : PERSON (string Address)

I'm trying to use the same property "Document" in FRIEND and BESTFRIEND, but not in BESBESTFRIEND so I don't want "Document" in root's class PERSON. When I try to make the Migration I get an error that says that I have an element created with the same key. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `[Column(Name = "Document")]` to the two document properties

Comment: Thank you! Now is working. Could you please explain about why this is happening?

Comment: well what is happening is that the attribute makes entity framework to see the two column as one and will not  raise exception. please can you mark it as an answer or upvote. Thank you

Comment: Is been a pleasure helping you.thank you too. if you have any entity framework, soa, wpf or wcf problem you can always let me know.thanks